# Break sentence in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

I am using FlexboxLayout manager and recyclerview to show list of sentences. When i am adding sentence into recyclerview if there is no room for whole sentence in left
it goes to bottom. Then i want break the sentence and fill available space into left and remains will go to bottom. Help me.

Comment: Add some code specifying what you had done. Maybe an adapter class of recycler view.